# erb template print newline inside code evaluation

Tags: ruby, erb

a puppet erb template that generate a dynamic content file:

```
<%
if @interfaces.count(',') > 0 then
  counter = 0
  @interfaces.split(',').each do |int|
  next if int == "lo"
  if has_variable?("ipaddress_#{int}")
    ip   = scope.lookupvar("ipaddress_#{int}")
    mask = scope.lookupvar("netmask_#{int}")
    cidr = scope.call_function('netmask_to_masklen',["#{mask}"])
    cidr_to_n = scope.call_function('cidr_to_network',["#{ip}/#{cidr}"])
    if ip =~ /192.168.0/
       x = ip
       $i1 = int
       $c_to_n1 = cidr_to_n
    else
       $y = ip
       $i2 = int
       $c_to_n2 = cidr_to_n
    end
  end
  end
end -%>
ip route add <%= $c_to_n1 %>/<%= $cidr %> dev <%=$i1%> src <%=$x%> table 192.168.0_RT
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1   dev <%=$i1%>        table 192.168.0_RT

ip route add <%= $c_to_n2 %>/<%= $cidr %> dev <%=$i2%> src <%=$y%> table 192.168.168_RT
ip route add default via 192.168.168.1   dev <%=$i2%>          table 192.168.168_RT
ip rule add from <%= $x %>/32   table 192.168.0_RT
ip rule add from <%= $y %>/32 table 192.168.168_RT
```

As for now code is working as expected, however if I put the lines( ip route...) between if/else everything is printed on same line w/o line break.
So the main question is how to make the code to look a bit cleaner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, to render these lines between the if block, you need to add an html line break <br> tag and then mark your strings as #html_safe or use the "#h" helper in the view.

For instance:

```
<% (1..4).each do |i| %>
  <% if i.even? %>
    <%= h "#{i} is even<br>" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= h "#{i} id odd<br>" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Should create html that renders like this:

```
1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
```

Comment: Thanks @ted-price,  indeed that is what I had intended to get as output ! +
the trick part of <% each block code %>